# Using list values to form single redis mget

Tags: list, clojure, redis

I have a clojure list

```
("mykey:1" "mykey:2" "mykey:3")
```

I want to use redis mget to fetch values of all keys

```
(mget mykey:1 mykey:2 mykey:3)
```

I'm using the wonderful [Carmine](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine) library.. I don't have any problem with it at all but when I try to use the list in a function

```
(defn get-keys
[k]
(mget k))
```

The key `k` actually includes the brackets too, since it's a list. Doing:

```
(mget (map #(%) k))
```

gets me nowhere either.

How do I now split them into individual keys so I can pass it to mget? is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Does using [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) work? As in `(apply mget '("mykey:1" "mykey:2" "mykey:3"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a collection that contains values you want to use as the arguments to a function, you should use [`apply`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply).

```
(def args '("mykey:1" "mykey:2" "mykey:3"))

(apply mget args)
; is equivalent to the call    
(mget "mykey:1" "mykey:2" "mykey:3")
```